# Is this the most efficient way to vertically slice a list of dictionaries for unique values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a list of dictionaries, and I'm looking for a unique list of values for one of the keys.

This is what I came up with, but can't help but wonder if its efficient, time and/or memory wise:

```
list(set([d['key'] for d in my_list]))
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Why do you want a list, if you want the elements to be unique?

Comment: Can you give us a sample data set?

Comment: @Lego: `my_list = [{'key': 1}, {'key': 2}, {'key': 2}, {'key': 3},]`

Comment: Looks like maybe you've chosen a poor data structure in the first place

Comment: @kojiro: That's exactly what the OP's code does, and there's no reason to believe his code is incorrect; he's just asking if there's a way to make it more efficient.

Comment: He says he's looking for *a unique list of one of the keys*, which is slightly different to *a list of keys*. The title of the question clarifies exactly: *slice a list of dictionaries for unique values*. I was sort of confused as well, so perhaps it's worth OP clarifying that sentence properly.

Comment: @kojiro: Since the OP wants to know if there's "a better way", I would assume the code is doing what is wanted.

Comment: @gnibbler Although I chose neither the data schema nor the scripting language, I've come to appreciate the latter constraint and to accept working with the former.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This:

```
list(set([d['key'] for d in my_list]))
```

… constructs a list of all values, then constructs a set of just the unique values, then constructs a list out of the set.

Let's say you had 10000 items, of which 1000 are unique. You've reduced final storage from 10000 items to 1000, which is great—but you've increased peak storage from 10000 to 11000 (because there clearly has to be a time when the entire list and almost the entire set are both in memory simultaneously).

There are two very simple ways to avoid this.

First (as long as you've got Python 2.4 or later) use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension. In most cases, including this one, that's just a matter of removing the square brackets or turning them into parentheses:

```
list(set(d['key'] for d in my_list))
```

Or, even more simply (with Python 2.7 or later), just construct the set directly by using a set comprehension instead of a list comprehension:

```
list({d['key'] for d in my_list})
```

If you're stuck with Python 2.3 or earlier, you'll have to write an explicit loop. And with 2.2 or earlier, there are no sets, so you'll have to fake it with a dict mapping each key to `None` or similar.

---

Beyond space, what about time? Well, clearly you have to traverse the entire list of 10000 dictionaries, and do an O(1) `dict.get` for each one.

The original version does a `list.append` (actually a slightly faster internal equivalent) for each of those steps, and then the `set` conversion is a traversal of a list of the same size with a `set.add` for each one, and then the `list` conversion is a traversal of a smaller set with a `list.append` for each one. So, it's O(N), which is clearly optimal algorithmically, and only worse by a smallish multiplier than just iterating the list and doing nothing.

The set version skips over the `list.append`s, and only iterates once instead of twice. So, it's also O(N), but with an even smaller multiplier. And the savings in memory management (if N is big enough to matter) may help as well.

Comment: Note: Set comprehension is in 3.x and 2.7

Comment: @zengr: And the question is tagged python-2.7.

Comment: @abarnert It still bears pointing out to the casual SO visitor.

Comment: Awesome.  Didn't know about set comprehension.